# How do I truncate a file in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, file-io, truncate

I have the following case. I have a big file say 1 KB. I want to read the first 100 bytes and then delete the 100 bytes read data from the file and then read next 100 bytes. To read 100 bytes is ok, but how do I delete 100 bytes from the file?

Comment: 1kb is not a big file. It is, in fact, a very small file. Unless you are in an embedded scenario with very limited memory, why don't you just read the entire file?

Answer (score 4):

This is commonly done as a multiple-step process:

1. Rename the original file.
2. Write the data you want into a new file with the original file name.
3. Delete the old file with the temporary name that contains the data you no longer want.

That way, if something were to go wrong, you could simply restore the original file that you renamed. Moving a file from one place to another is implemented this way, as well.

However, if you don't want to do this, the [`SetEndOfFile` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531.aspx) is another viable option to truncate the contents of a file in-place. From the documentation:

> Sets the physical file size for the specified file to the current position of the file pointer.
>
> The physical file size is also referred to as the end of the file. The `SetEndOfFile` function can be used to truncate or extend a file.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP wants to delete data at the top, beginning, of the file.  The `SetEndOfFile` function may delete data that has not been read yet.

Comment: @Thomas: That's possible. I assumed the definition of the word "truncate" was still the same since the last time I looked it up. In either case, the first part of my answer applies. The second is useful for those who might want to redesign their logic to do the more normal thing of truncating data at the end of a file.

Comment: You can make those 3 steps only if no other thread is writing to the file or using it

Comment: @RomanDorevich: Yes, obviously. You can't modify files that are in use by other processes. The question doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 3):

That wouldn't be called *truncating*; that term refers to removing data from the end, not the beginning. I'm not aware of any operating system where this is possible, other than by copying the contents of the file to a new file, starting at the 100th byte.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx which explains in detail why it's not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting data that has been processed in a file is time consuming and in most cases not necessary.

Deleting data near the top or middle of the file requires writing a new file, which takes time and disk space.  Most applications will read and process the entire file then rename the file (with a backup extension).  This is useful for debugging purposes.  Deleting an entire file is often a faster operation that writing a new file without processed data.

Deletions should only take place when necessary.  For files, one can store an offset of where the valid data begins, thus reducing the need to delete data from a file.  For secure purposes, overwriting data in the file is often faster then creating a new file without the processed data.

First try writing your program to not delete data in the file.  Only delete as necessary, after the program is robust and working correctly.  Many people would suggest to only delete files when there is no more space on drive.